# int cannot be dereferenced error in dr java

Tags: java

I'm trying to split a string into 3 integers but i'm getting the error "int cannot be dereferenced" on dr java please help

code:

```
public class ValidDate

{
  public int validYear;
  public int validMonth;
  public int validDay;

  public ValidDate(String validDate )throws Exception
  {
  validYear = Integer.parseInt(validDate).split[1];
 validMonth = Integer.parseInt(validDate).split[2];
    validDay = Integer.parseInt(validDate).split[3];
.....}
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(validDate)` return an `int`. `int` is not have `split` function. Tips for you: let's use split function of String to split year, month, day => after that parse these string to int

Comment: @TuyenNguyen Look at the code again. With *that* syntax, `split` is not a method. It is a *field* of type `int[]` or `Integer[]`. Notice the use of `[]`, not `()`.

Comment: If you want to parse a date string, why don't you just use one of the built-in date parsers ([`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) or [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html))?

Comment: @Andreas you should notice that the `Integer.parseInt` return an `int` and the `int` or `Integer` is not have any field or method `split`. Also the `int[]` or `Integer[]` did not have field `split`

Comment: @TuyenNguyen I know that. I was just pointing out that you're assuming OP was trying to use `split()` method call, when syntax isn't method call syntax. So, your statement that "`int` is not have `split` function", while correct, is not consistent with syntax. Saying "`int` does not have `split` *field*" would be more on point, with the code shown.

Answer (score 0):

First split the string, then parse them to int. Like this:

```
public ValidDate(String validDate )throws Exception
{
    validYear = Integer.parseInt(validDate.split(" ")[0]);
    validMonth = Integer.parseInt(validDate.split(" ")[1]);
    validDay = Integer.parseInt(validDate.split(" ")[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[When looking at the documentation for Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) we see that it is very specific about the type of String that can be fed to `parseInt()`.

Also, it seems that you are trying to access some variable on the `int` returned from `Integer.parseInt(validDate)` called `split` which you believe to be an array. However, you are unable to do that because `int` is a primitive type. This is the source of the error you are seeing.

Comment: 1) You could split on "\\D+", since you want result to be all digit values. --- 2) Did you mean `dateValues`, not `validDate`, on the last two lines? --- 3) Did you mean `[2]` on the last line?

Comment: @Andreas For your points 2 and 3, that is what I meant. I will edit it so that it is correct. As far as your first point goes, that is true, but as I say in the comment, it really should be up to OP to decide on that.

Comment: @Andreas I'm just going to remove the code example. In retrospect, OP did not provide enough information for me to give him a meaningful example to look at.